# SQL Server Update value in a column with GROUP BY and condition of sum and a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Assignment | Type | Amount | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1018140292 | SA | 14.51 | Currency Variance |
| 1018140292 | RV | -16.56 | Currency Variance |

Scenario :
I need to update the Comments column in a database if the sum of the Amount column value of the multiple line item with the same Assignment is within range
(-10) - (+10). The data will be group by the Assignment column. However I am having a challenge where we only can sum up if the Assignment contain column Type with "SA" AND "RV" when we group by.

Below is my query that I have try.

```
update tbl_NO300_Details
set Comments='Currency Variance'
where Assignment in(
select Assignment 
from tbl_NO300_Details Intbl where Type in ('RV', 'SA')
group by Intbl.Waybill,right(Shipment_Date,7 )
having count(*)>1 and sum(cast(Amount as float))>-10 and sum(cast(LC_Amount as float))<10)
```

The Problem :

When I encounter such case when there is multiple line with just only SA, it will also update the Comments column with "Currency Varience" which is not correct. We need to have "RV" and "SA" in this case.

| Assignment | Type | Amount | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1018140292 | SA | 5.00 | Currency Variance |
| 1018140292 | SA | 4.00 | Currency Variance |

The correct output should be, it will not update the Comments column (should be blank) :

| Assignment | Type | Amount | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1018140292 | SA | 5.00 |  |
| 1018140292 | SA | 4.00 |  |

Appreciate if you can help solve my issue.

Thank You.

Comment: Side note, converting a value which is clearly meant to represent a monetary value to a `float` is a very poor idea. `float` is (surprise!) a floating point value and is *not* accurate. You could easily introduce errors using such a data type for monetary values.

Comment: Also, `and Type in ('RV', 'SA')` should be in the `WHERE` *not* the `HAVING`.

Comment: @Larnu , I have edit my query with the  where Type in ('RV', 'SA') in the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **windowed conditional aggregates** to do the calculations.

Do this inside a CTE or derived table, and **update directly** through that.

```sql
UPDATE t
SET Comments = 'Currency Variance'
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        countRV = COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'RV' THEN 1 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY Intbl.Waybill, RIGHT(Shipment_Date, 7)),
        countSA = COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'SA' THEN 1 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY Intbl.Waybill, RIGHT(Shipment_Date, 7)),
        sm = SUM(CASE WHEN Type IN ('RV', 'SA') THEN Amount END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY Intbl.Waybill, RIGHT(Shipment_Date, 7))
    FROM tbl_NO300_Details Intbl
) t
WHERE countRV > 0 AND countSA > 0
  AND sm > -10 AND sm < 10
```

> **Notes:**
>
> - Don't convert to float if you don't have to. If you *need* to convert strings to numbers, convert to `decimal` if you can
> - Unclear what `RIGHT(Shipment_Date, 7)` is for. If you are trying to strip out times from `datetime` values, this is not the way to do it

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, thank you for your help, however, ii have try the query, it seems return the incorrect output for the case both Type are "SA". You can refer this fiddle.

[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea6641e95173bcfe4a942c224455f7ec)

Comment: I edited it very shortly after I posted it, that should have worked barring couple syntax errors, now fixed. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d80a4cbefa7bbf5664723934c77b2d33